# Is it possible to create single page application with laravel 5.4 and jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.4

I need to create a single page application in laravel 5.4. I will be using jQuery with that. But is it possible to create the single page application with laravel blade?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create single page application in laravel. Mostly in single page application you need to use rest services (laravel is used for rest) and other jquery frameworks.